# PLSQL Insert and update another table with trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I am new to plsql;
I have 2 tables, tableA and tableB.

tableA is my main table. After insert or update on tableA I want to update it with its related table.

For example: tableA has the column named 'GID_FROM_B' and tableB has the column named 'GID'. I can match this table's values with id and counter. According to below table I want to add values of (2, 5, '') to tableA from my interface. And gid_from_b will be updated with trigger. And I wrote the trigger below.

```
tableA:
id     |   counter  |   gid_from_b  |
1             3            xyz                            


tableB:
id     |   counter  |      gid      |
1             3            xyz                            
2             5            abc
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER gid_update
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON DBO.TABLEA
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE TABLEA
   SET GID_FROM_B =  TABLEB.GID
   WHERE TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID AND TABLEA.COUNTER = TABLEB.COUNTER;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run any update statement, simply use a select into :NEW.gid_from_b. Note that it should be a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER` if you want to modify values of `:NEW` columns.

This assumes that your `TableB` has a single row for each id,counter combination. If not, you may have to fetch `MAX(gid)`  `MIN(gid)`or whatever suits you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER gid_update
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TABLEA
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.gid_from_b IS NULL)
BEGIN
 SELECT gid INTO 
    :NEW.gid_from_b FROM tableB b 
  WHERE b.id =:NEW.id AND b.counter = :NEW.counter;
END;
/
```

[**dbfiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76112525305c5d7dad7467719cccd5fa)

Comment: Can I check if gid value is null or not? I mean if the user entered a value for gid in the interface trigger will be ignored.

Comment: @FatihKara : So if user entered the value, which column are you going to populate the values?  the same `gid_from_b`  or do you have any other column in TableA called gid?.  Importantly, If that was your intention,  I don't see the need for a Trigger. You could simply handle it in your insert or update.

Comment: In the interface there will be 3 textboxes for each column in the tableA. And 3rd textbox will refer for gid_from_b and it can be nullable. If user enters a value it will be inserted. If not it will take its value from tableB via trigger. I want to do this.

Comment: @FatihKara : I modified the Trigger and the demo link. Take a look now. Do mark the question as answered(√ symbol)  if this helped you, before u disappear with the answer :-)

Comment: It really helped but I have now another issue. What about If I add a 3rd table same as above tableC. Is it possible to check if there is insert or update on tableA and add the value from tableB to tableC?

Comment: @FK : Please try joining the 3rd table in the select query. If you have issues, you may ask another question with the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For only `INSERT` operation to be performed, we need to replace `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` with `BEFORE INSERT`, where not possible to create an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` with `:new` prefixed columns.

The following suits well for your aim :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER gid_update
BEFORE INSERT ON TableA
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  for c in ( select b.gid from tableB b where b.id = :new.id and b.counter = :new.counter )
  loop
    :new.gid_from_b := c.gid; 
  end loop; 
END;
```